# Using Python to list all incoming connection in Linux

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to get Python to listen to my network and list all incoming connections as long as it runs. But I hit a brick wall and can't seem to find how. Any suggestions? Using Python 2.7.3

Comment: Start here: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html. Also possibly a (C based) socket API tutorial, since the Python standard library mirrors it fairly closely. (I'm not sure which one would be good, but the documentation I linked to mentions several.)

Comment: Please expand upon where exactly you hit a brick wall. Starting the python interpreter? Finding a library to use? Using a library?

Comment: Are you talking about just listening on a port or having your python application actively sniff your network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@millimoose:
I don't think (s)he needs/wants to listen on all sockets using python.
What they're more likely after is
[Python bindings to libpcap](http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `netstat` to list all incoming network connections. Someone has even written a Python implementation of `netstat`: http://voorloopnul.com/blog/a-python-netstat-in-less-than-100-lines-of-code/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague on details but if all you want to do is watch inbound connections to your machine, you can do that with just a couple lines of python.

```
from socket import *

rawSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)
rawSocket.bind(('IP_ON_IFACE_TO_LISTEN_ON', 0))

while True:

    data = rawSocket.recv(2048)

    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure

    # Internet Header Length; Have to determine where the IP header ends
    ihl = ord(data[0]) & 15
    ip_payload = data[ihl*4:]

    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure

    # Match SYN but not SYN/ACK
    if (ord(ip_payload[13]) & 18) == 2:
        src_addr = inet_ntoa(data[12:16])
        dst_addr = inet_ntoa(data[16:20])

        # Could use struct.unpack, might be clearer
        src_port = (ord(ip_payload[0]) << 8) + ord(ip_payload[1])
        dst_port = (ord(ip_payload[2]) << 8) + ord(ip_payload[3])

        src_str = (src_addr+':'+str(src_port)).ljust(22)
        dst_str = (dst_addr+':'+str(dst_port))

        print "%s=> %s" % (src_str, dst_str)
```

This will print all inbound TCP packets that have the SYN flag set, regardless of an RST or ICMP responses.  Your question states 'list all incoming connections', since UDP is connectionless, I *assume* thats what you're asking about.

FWIW